# How to combine linq expressions into one in order to model given sql?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to model this sql in linq

```
select
    [a].[BuyOutPrice],
    [a].[BidFloorPrice],
    [b].[BidCeil] as [BidderBidCeilPrice],
    [b].[BidPrice] as [BidderBidPrice],
    [s].[UserId] as [SellerUserId],
    [LeadingPriceBid].[Price] as [LeadingBidPrice]
from [Auctions] as [a]
join [Sellers] as [s]
    on [a].[Id] = [s].[AuctionId]
left join (
    select
        [lb].[AuctionId],
        [b].[Price] as [Price]
    from [LeadingBid] as [lb]
    join [Bid] as [b]
        on [lb].[BidId] = [b].[id]
) as [LeadingPriceBid]
    on [a].[Id] = [LeadingPriceBid].[AuctionId]
left join (
    select
        [Bidder].[BidCeil] as [BidCeil],
        [Bidder].[AuctionId] as [AuctionId],
        [Bid].[Price] as [BidPrice]
    from [Bidder]
    join [Bid]
        on [Bidder].[BidId] = [Bid].[Id]
    where [Bidder].[UserId] = 1
        and not exists (
            select 1
            from [Sellers] as [s]
            where [s].[AuctionId] = [Bidder].[AuctionId]
                and [s].[UserId] = [Bidder].[UserId]
        )
) as [b]
    on [a].[Id] = [b].[AuctionId]
where [a].[Id] = 1
```

I can split this query in two parts and write them as linq

```
var auctionQuery =
from auction in dbctx.Auctions
where auction.Id == 1
join seller in dbctx.Sellers on auction.Id equals seller.AuctionId
join leadingBid in dbctx.LeadingBid on auction.Id equals leadingBid.AuctionId into leadingBids
from leadingBid in leadingBids.DefaultIfEmpty()
join leadingBidPrice in dbctx.Bid on leadingBid.BidId equals leadingBidPrice.Id into leadingPriceBids
from leadingBidPrice in leadingPriceBids.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
    AuctionId = auction.Id,
    BuyoutPrice = auction.BuyoutPrice,
    BidFloorPrice = auction.BidFloorPrice,
    SellerUserId = seller.UserId,
    LeadingBidPrice = leadingBidPrice == null ? (decimal?)null : leadingBidPrice.Price
};

var bidderQuery = from bidder in dbctx.Bidder.Where(bidder => bidder.UserId == 1)
join bid in dbctx.Bid on bidder.BidId equals bid.Id
where !(from seller in dbctx.Sellers where seller.AuctionId == bidder.AuctionId select seller).Any(d => d.UserId == bidder.UserId)
select new
{
   AuctionId = bidder.AuctionId,
   BidCeil = bidder.BidCeil,
   Price = bid.Price
};
```

But I cannot manage to combine those two linq queries into one in a way that one sql command is generated. No matter how I try two sql commands are executed at best.

PROGRESS

Closest that I got so far

```
from auction in dbctx.Auctions
where auction.Id == id
join seller in dbctx.Sellers on auction.Id equals seller.AuctionId
join leadingBid in dbctx.LeadingBid on auction.Id equals leadingBid.AuctionId into leadingBids
from leadingBid in leadingBids.DefaultIfEmpty()
join leadingBidPrice in dbctx.Bid on leadingBid.BidId equals leadingBidPrice.Id into leadingPriceBids
from leadingBidPrice in leadingPriceBids.DefaultIfEmpty()

join bidder in dbctx.Bidder.Where(bidder => bidder.UserId == userId)
    on new { AuctionId = auction.Id, BidderIsSeller = false } equals new { AuctionId = bidder.AuctionId, BidderIsSeller = (from seller in dbctx.Sellers where seller.AuctionId == bidder.AuctionId select seller).Any(d => d.UserId == bidder.UserId) } into bidders
from bidder in bidders.DefaultIfEmpty()
join bidderBid in dbctx.Bid on bidder.BidId equals bidderBid.Id into bids
from bidderBid in bids.DefaultIfEmpty()

select new
{
    AuctionId = auction.Id,
    BuyoutPrice = auction.BuyoutPrice,
    BidFloorPrice = auction.BidFloorPrice,
    SellerUserId = seller.UserId,
    LeadingBidPrice = leadingBidPrice == null ? (decimal?)null : leadingBidPrice.Price
};
```

Yields me

```
FROM "Auctions" AS "auction"
INNER JOIN "Sellers" AS "seller" ON "auction"."Id" = "seller"."AuctionId"
LEFT JOIN "LeadingBid" AS "leadingBid" ON "auction"."Id" = "leadingBid"."AuctionId"
LEFT JOIN "Bid" AS "leadingBidPrice" ON "leadingBid"."BidId" = "leadingBidPrice"."Id"
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT "bidder0"."UserId", "bidder0"."AuctionId", "bidder0"."BidAuctionId", "bidder0"."BidCeil", "bidder0"."BidId", "bidder0"."BidUserId"
    FROM "Bidder" AS "bidder0"
    WHERE "bidder0"."UserId" = @__userId_1
) AS "t" ON ("auction"."Id" = "t"."AuctionId") AND (FALSE = (
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM "Sellers" AS "seller1"
            WHERE ("seller1"."AuctionId" = "t"."AuctionId") AND ("seller1"."UserId" = "t"."UserId"))
        THEN TRUE::bool ELSE FALSE::bool
    END
))
LEFT JOIN "Bid" AS "bidderBid" ON "t"."BidId" = "bidderBid"."Id"
WHERE "auction"."Id" = @__id_0
ORDER BY "auction"."Id", "leadingBid"."BidId", (SELECT 1), "t"."BidId"
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: why do you need to rewrite it to LINQ? isn't i better to just have SQL and put in i.e. StoreProcedure and run? What's the purpose here?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik Consistency!

Comment: All these joins make me presume that you don't have any navigation properties. It's highly recommended to fix that first so the LINQ part of the query will become much simpler. It looks like there could also be a navigation property like `Auction.Bidders`.